# |f| is bounded and |f-g| is bounded, is |g| also bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I know that $|f| < \infty$ and that $|f-g|<\epsilon$

I know that
$$||f|-|g||\leq|f-g|<\epsilon$$
so either
$$|f|-|g|<\epsilon$$
or
$$|g|-|f|<\epsilon$$

If $|g|-|f|<\epsilon$, it is clear that $|g|$ is bounded but what if $|f|-|g|<\epsilon$? Then $-|g|<\epsilon-|f|$

Is there a way to continue or is it not possible to prove that $|g|$ is bounded?

Comment: $|g| = |(g-f)+f| \leq |g-f| + |f|$.

Comment: @Rigel I was about to post this as an answer...

Comment: For any real number we have $a\le|a|$ and $-a\le|a|$.

Comment: @Rigel Thanks I forgot about this method, can you please just post the solution so I can mark it solved?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: imho, there is nothing wrong with posting a similar answer if it was independently arrived at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested:
$$
|g| = |(g-f)+f| \leq |g-f| + |f|.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$||f|-|g|| = |f|-|g|$ only if $|g|<|f|$ in which case $|g|<|f|<\infty$.